# How to update attribute from not null to allow null in rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I want to do a column from my table from not null to allow null through rails migrations? How to do this? Do i change the original migration which created the table or write a new one? And what to do in it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need `change_column`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column

Create a new migration file with this

```
change_column :my_table, :my_column, :integer, :null => true
```

Or you can use a specialised command for this ([change_column_null](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SQLiteAdapter/change_column_null)):

```
change_column_null :my_table, :my_column, true
```